# Samhain - Monitor /var/spool/cron/crontabs/

Tags: linux, monitoring, cron

Using [Samhain](https://la-samhna.de/samhain/) File Integrity Monitoring, I'm trying to monitor changes to the crontab entries. I added the below entry to `/etc/samhain/samhainrc`

```
dir=/var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

then I added an entry to the root account at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`  and when I try to do `Samhain -t check`, Samhain does not report the changes. It works when I try with any other file. any help?

Comment: the directory where are cron files is `/var/spool/cron`

Comment: Yes, I missed `cron` in the question.

Comment: You do not get my point, please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should define the directory on this way:

```
dir=/var/spool/cron
```

And reconsider the monitoring of this directory because cron jobs change in normal circumstances.
On Ubuntu 16... the line should be:

```
dir=/var/spool/cron/crontab
```

If you want to monitor particular cron use config like:

```
file=/var/spool/cron/root
```

Ubuntu:

```
file=/var/spool/cron/crontab/root
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to monitor the root's crontab, is any other better way to do it?

Comment: You will better monitor the file, not directory. See my edited answer